# C# MVC: using CSS from another location

Tags: c#, .net

I need to keep all images, css, etc in one folder structure and all code in another. I'm trying to get the src paths right and just cannot do it.

I have css in the following structure:  /public/content/*.css
and all project code in this:  /protected/Code/...
And public and protected are in the same folder.

How do I use the public resource in the protected projects?

Cheers,

Comment: What do you mean "cannot do it"?  What have you tried and how has it failed?

Comment: example:
index.aspx is located in /protected/app/index.aspx and is running.

A css link needs <link href-"public/shared/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

where /public and /protected are at the same level in the file directory tree.

How do I tell it to look outside the scope of the application folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something where you need relative path names. For instance, if you are inside  folder/protected/Code and you need to access folder/public/content/main.css, you would use the path ../../public/content/main.css

Inside folder/protected/Code, .. refers to folder/protected, and ../.. refers to folder.

Comment: In the end I just had both projects running, and referenced the files I needed using http://.... That way I can share some data between projects.